# How to solve the TypeORM to use at application and the tests

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I'm having problems with TypeORM, before I had a configuration in which it worked the requests I sent via Insomnia, however, I wasn't able to make it use it in tests, such as creating the connection, closing the connection and cleaning the base of data.

I ended up changing the ORM configuration so that I could do these operations in the tests, but now it starts to not work when I want to test via Insomnia.

### ormconfig.json current

So I don't know how I can use it in the main project file

```
import { createConnection, getConnection } from 'typeorm';

const connection = {
  async create(){
    await createConnection();
  },

  async close(){
    await getConnection().close(); 
  },

  async clear(){
    const connection = getConnection();
    const entities = connection.entityMetadatas;

    entities.forEach(async (entity) => {
      const repository = connection.getRepository(entity.name);
      await repository.query(`DELETE FROM ${entity.tableName}`);
    });
  },
};

export default connection;
```

### ormconsig.json before

This way, in the project's initialization file, I just did an import `import from "./infra/typeorm"`.

```
import { createConnection, getConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';

interface IOptions {
  host: string;
}

export default getConnectionOptions().then(options => {
  const newOptions = options as IOptions;
  newOptions.host = 'database_clina';
  createConnection({
    ...options,
  });
});
```

### src/index.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import connection from "./infra/typeorm";
import express from "express";

import { usersRoutes } from "./routes/users.routes";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/users", usersRoutes);

export { app };
```

### Error

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.`

Answer (score 0):

> I `suspect you are missing some steps`, for e.g. this is needed to generate your connections... `"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate --config src/config/ormconfig.json --connection  --name "`

Add this line of code `console.log("env", process.env.NODE_ENV, connection!.name);` to debug your connection.

#### Now *double check with the docs*: How create a connection https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/connection.md

I usually have both default and production configs and then switch to production.

---

1. Assuming you setup TypeORM with  someModule/or TypeOrmModule as below, then check if you have First setup your connection like so in the module...

```
 // Debug connection
 console.log("env", process.env.NODE_ENV, connection!.name);
```

---

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: config.db.type,
      host: config.db.host,
      port: config.db.port,
      username: config.db.user,
      password: config.db.password,
      database: config.db.database,
      entities: [
        __dirName + '/../../dtos/entities/*.entity.js',
      ]
    })
```

2. Double Check and establish the connection inside a function, then create/get access to the repo.

---

```
//  this should usually work from inside a function or a factory function so its available.
 const ticketsRepository = getRepository(Tickets); inside a function
```

---

If all of that doesn't work, just follow this pattern. For easy future access create a `factory` function for the connections, then import it as needed. See here on [github sample](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4010#issuecomment-612149115)

```
//factory function
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm/browser';
import { UserEntity, UserModel } from './schema';

export function getUserRepository() {
  return getRepository<UserModel>(UserEntity);
}

____

// now import and consume it
import { getUserRepository } from '...';

getUserRepository().findOne(1);
```

---

3. Beside having `ormconfig.json` (BTW in your question you misspelled this, assuming its a typeo but doesnt hurt to double check) you need these commands in your `package.json` for bootstrapping to generate the connections.

```
"typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm",
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate --config src/config/ormconfig.json --connection  --name ",
"migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run"
```